# ¿Cómo implemento (SSR) Server Side Rendering en React si he utilizado Create-React-App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Prácticamente estoy tratando de implementar **Server Side Rendering con React** pero con las configuraciones que te brinda el create-react-app desde el principio, lo he hecho anteriormente pero instalando react, react-dom, etc etc de forma manual, pero quiero hacer lo mismo usando el create-react-app, ¿será que no se puede?. PD: lo quiero hacer usando ExpressJS

Comment: Creo que se puede, pero te ahorras problemas usando NextJS.

Comment: Entiendo, gracias por la sugerencia.